# Issue with tapply

Tags: r

I am using tapply to combine a table by Sample ID(SID). For the first sample on the list there are 3 measurements but it appears as only one.

I have 4 things that need to pass to the new table. First is SID. Second is the mean of the areas for all measurements that have that SID. Third is all the Distances. Finally the number of measurements.

```
cases_iTLS <- data.frame(unique(iTLS$SID))
colnames(cases_iTLS)[colnames(cases_iTLS)=="unique.iTLS.SID."] <- "SID"
cases_iTLS$SID <- factor(cases_iTLS$SID)

# Average of TLS on one slide for area
cases_iTLS$Area_iTLS <- tapply(iTLS$Area, iTLS$SID,FUN=mean) 

# Average of TLS on one slide for distance
cases_iTLS$Distance_iTLS <- tapply(iTLS$Distance, iTLS$SID,FUN=mean) 

# Number of measurements per SID
cases_iTLS$Count_iTLS <- tapply(iTLS$Region_Index, iTLS$SID,FUN=length) 


SID       Region_index   Area         Distance    Type    Location
112906    1              53531.53     71.982      iTLS    intratumoral
112906    3              76809.61     97.384      iTLS    intratumoral
112906    5              40937.30     9.643       iTLS    intratumoral
112947    1              35071.66     2.067       iTLS    intratumoral
112947    3              17979.88     36.319      iTLS
```

Comment: What is your question? What is the error or undesired result of your code?

Comment: The output for the first sample is Count_iTLS = 1. But in the input there are 3 rows with unique Region_index. The desired output should be Count_iTLS=3. Additionally, the two other tapply are giving incorrect means.

Comment: With no example of structure nor datas is difficult to answer. Is the mean false because of use or not use of `NA` ? : [How to pass na.rm as argument to tapply?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26644583/10489562)

Comment: @phili_b I have added the structure of the data to the main question. There are not cells in the data that are NA

Comment: With a `dput(myvariable)` to put here the structure would be easier to test :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need to run separate aggregate functions (`mean` and `length`) across multiple columns (*Area*, *Distance*, and *SID*), consider using `aggregate` for grouping aggregation to return a data frame.

Usually, `tapply` runs on a single numeric metric not across columns or functions to return a single named, atomic vector. Below calls a `do.call` + `data.frame` to bind the nested result of multiple aggregations

**`aggregate`**

```
# AGGREGATE ACROSS COLS AND FUNCS
cases_iTLS <- aggregate(cbind(Area, Distance, Region_Index) ~ SID, iTLS, 
                        function(x) c(mean=mean(x), count = length(x))

# BIND NESTED, UNDERLYING RESULTS
cases_iTLS <- do.call(data.frame, cases_iTLS)

# KEEP NEEDED COLUMNS
cases_iTL <- cases_iTL[c("SID", "Area.mean", "Distance.mean", "Region_Index.count")
```

---

**`tapply`**

Should you want to go the `tapply` route, consider building a matrix of your separate aggregations with `rbind` and transpose `t`:

```
cases_iTL_mat <- with(iTLS, 
                         t(rbind(Area_mean = tapply(Area, SID, FUN=mean) ,
                                 Distance_mean = tapply(Distance, SID, FUN=mean),
                                 Region_count = tapply(Region_Index, SID, FUN=length)
                          ))
                 )
```

---

**`by`**

And I would be remiss not to point `by` (the object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`):

```
cases_iTL_mat <- do.call(rbind, 
        by(iTLS, iTLS$SID, function(sub) {
               c(Area_mean = mean(sub$Area),
                 Distance_mean = mean(sub$Distance),
                 Region_count = length(sub$Region_Index))
          })
)
```

Comment: This seems to work. I  just had question about the "Keep Needed Columns" part. Am I required to uses those names to call the function or is that just renaming the columns

Comment: Period-qualifying names derive from the aggregate call on columns but can be renamed afterwards or within the `c()` function. Specifically, inside `aggregate`, `c(Andre_func = mean(x))` renders at the end as `Area.Andre_func`.